# Apache kafka - Consuming messages before time or in time

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I want to consume messages in say 2 hours (not fixed, some messages i want to consume in a day). Is there a way i can utilize timestamps for this? I am aiming to replace existing schedule based implementation. Kafka streams looks promising, with new session window but as far as i can tell it is meant for totally different thing.

`consumer.seek()` only accepts offset and partition, so thats not helpful either.

Comment: What do you mean by "in 2 hours" or "in a day" ? Do you mean "the last 2 hours" or "the next 2 hours" or a time frame of 2 hours (with know start time) ?

Comment: User books a ride, i want to perform an action 20 minutes before pickup. What i mean by "in 2 hours or in a day " is you can schedule a ride for tomorrow while i can schedule it for today.

Comment: "aiming to replace existing schedule based implementation" -> I have no idea how you could leverage Kafka for this in an elegant way. Kafka is good if you have an even and want to react on it -- however, you want to take some action in the future -- thus, you would need to *generate* a message in the future (or similar). Kafka seems not to be a good fit this this. Btw: there is also `consumer.offsetsForTimes()` that allows you to exploit Kafka's timestamp based index -- not sure if this helps...